# A puzzle about this/@ in Javascript/Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, this, coffeescript, v8

I'm working through Trevor Burnham's *CoffeeScript* book and I've run into a weird puzzle concerning `this`/`@`. The puzzle has a few parts (and I may be just very confused), so I'll try to make this as clear as I can.

The main problem I'm having is that I get varied and inconsistent results running *the same* code through different REPLs and interpreters. I'm testing with (1) the `coffee` REPL and interpreter, (2) Node's REPL and interpreter and (3) v8's REPL and interpreter.

Here's the code, first as Coffeescript then as Javascript:

```
// coffeescript
setName = (name) -> @name = name

setName 'Lulu'
console.log name
console.log @name

// Javascript via the coffee compiler
(function() {
  var setName;
  setName = function(name) {
    return this.name = name;
  };
  setName('Lulu');
  // console.log for node below - print for v8
  // uncomment one or the other depending on what you're trying
  // console.log(name);
  // console.log(this.name);
  // print(name);
  // print(this.name);
}).call(this);
```

Here are the results:

```
$ coffee setName.coffee
Lulu
undefined

# coffee REPL
# This appears to be a bug in the REPL
# See https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1444
coffee> setName = (name) -> @name = name
[Function]
coffee> setName 'Lulu'
'Lulu'
coffee> console.log name
ReferenceError: name is not defined
    at repl:2:1
    at Object.eval (/Users/telemachus/local/node-v0.4.8/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script.js:89:15)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/Users/telemachus/local/node-v0.4.8/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/repl.js:39:28)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:153:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:408:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:585:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (readline.js:73:12)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at ReadStream._emitKey (tty_posix.js:307:10)

coffee> console.log @name
undefined

$ v8 setName.js
Lulu
Lulu

# v8 REPL
>> (function(){var setName; setName=function(name){return this.name=name;};setName('Lulu');print(name);print(this.name);}).call(this);
Lulu
Lulu

# Switch print to console.log or require puts from sys
$ node setName.js
Lulu
undefined

# node REPL
> (function() {
...   var setName;
...   setName = function(name) {
...     return this.name = name;
...   };
...   setName('Lulu');
...    console.log(name);
...    console.log(this.name);
... }).call(this);
Lulu
Lulu
```

So the real questions, I suppose, are (1) what results should I expect and (2) why can't these interpreters and REPLs get along? (My going theory is that v8 is right: in the global context `name` and `this.name` should be the same thing, I would have thought. But I'm very ready to believe that I don't understand `this` in Javascript.)

**Edit**: If I add `this.name = null`/`@name = null` before calling `setName` (as Pointy suggests below) then Coffeescript and Node give me 'Lulu' and 'null' back but v8 still returns 'Lulu' for both. (v8 still makes more sense to me here. I set `name` to `null` initially in the global context, but then `setName` sets it (in the global context) to 'Lulu'. So afterwards, this is what I should see there.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, first off, there's a bug with the CoffeeScript REPL, [issue 1444](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1444), which I reported after Telemachus brought this to my attention.

But the more interesting issue here (and one that I need to note in [my CoffeeScript book](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript)) is that `this` in the outermost scope of a Node.js module isn't `global`—it's that module's `exports`. Try this out:

```
console.log this is exports
console.log do -> this is global
```

You'll find that both statements evaluate to `true` when you run that code in a Node module. That's why `name` and `@name` evaluate to different things: `name` by itself will always point to `global.name`, unless it's in the scope of a `var name` declaration; but `@name` will only point to `global.name` in a function called in the `global` context (the default). In a Node.js module, outside of any function, it'll point to `exports.name`.

Comment: Bingo - and we have a winner. Thanks to all for helping me to see this more clearly. The bit about Node's environment was the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: Excellent! So simple and yet, I'm so used to avoiding global objects in JS that the `exports` scoping would never have occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you get different results, but I know that the invocation of a function implicitly involves setting `this`. The inner function "setName()" therefore has its very own `this` value independent of the value of `this` in the outer function in which it is defined. Thus, the fact that you set `this` via that ".call()" invocation has no effect whatsoever on the `this` value inside the inner "setName()" function, because when "setName()" is called there's no receiver involved.

Comment: You mean the `(function(){...}).call(this)` that Coffeescript wraps around the entire thing, yes? The Coffeescript compiler wraps whatever code you give it that way. I'm familiar with the similar `function(){...}()` for namespacing. The addition of `.call(this)` seems to be just to make explicit that the whole (wrapped) thing is global, but I don't really know.

Comment: Either way, *in this case* isn't `this` the global environment for `setName`? And if that's so, shouldn't `this.name` and `name` both point to the same thing (assuming nothing else has set `this` differently).

Comment: You're probably right.  The point I was making is that `this` inside "setName()" is going to be the global context reference, regardless of what `this` is inside that outer wrapper function.  Now, like I said, it's not clear why the results are different.  It might be interesting to add the line "this['name'] = null;" right before your "setName" function, because that will create a "name" property on the global object before the function tries to set it.

Comment: Tried it: v8 still says 'Lulu' both times and now Coffeescript and Node give 'Lulu' and 'null'. My instinct is that v8 is getting it right and the other two not, but mostly my head hurts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much CoffeeScript but a fair bit about JavaScript so I can only attempt to explain this from the point of view of what the compiled code does (or should be doing):

```
(function(){
  // In here "this" === [global]
  //
  // The purpose of this wrapper pattern is that it causes "this" to be
  // the global object but all var declared variables will still be 
  // scoped by the function.

  var ctx = this;     // let's keep test a ref to current context

  var setName;
  setName = function(name) {
    console.log(this === ctx);   // !! true !!

    // Because in here "this" is the global context/object
    // this is setting [global].name = name
    return this.name = name;
  };

  setName('Lulu');         // It's context will be [global]

  console.log(name);       // (name === [global].name) == true
  console.log(this.name);  // (this.name === [global].name) == true

}).call(this);
```

What is (or should be) happening is effectively this (assuming browser where global is `window`):

```
(function() {
  var setName;
  setName = function(name) {
    return window.name = name;
  };
  setName('Lulu');
  console.log(window.name);   // 'Lulu'
  console.log(window.name);   // 'Lulu'
}).call(this);
```

So, why doesn't it match up between the engines?

Because the different environments use different means of handing the global object to you and handling scoping. It's hard to say with certainty and every environment may have a separate reason for its behavior. It depends very much on how they evaluate the code (this is assuming none of the engines have bugs).

Comment: Thanks for the careful explanation and the clear description.

Comment: Well, at least I am able to confirm that your theory was right: `name` and `this.name` should indeed be the same thing in the global context. :-)