# What is the context for `this` in Node.js when run as a script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, this

From the node REPL:

```
$ node
> var x = 50
> console.log(x)
50
> console.log(this.x)
50
> console.log(this === global)
true
```

Everything makes sense. However, when I have a script:

```
$ cat test_this.js 
var x = 50;
console.log(x);
console.log(this.x);
console.log(this === global);
$ node test_this.js 
50
undefined
false
```

Not what I expected.

I don't really have a problem with the REPL behaving differently from a script, but where exactly in the Node documentation does it say something like "NOTE: when you run a script, the value of `this` is *not* set to `global`, but rather to ___________." Does anyone know, what `this` refers to in the global context when run as a script? Googling "nodejs this global context script" takes me to [this page](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) which looks very promising, as it describes contexts for running scripts, but it doesn't seem to mention the use of the `this` expression anywhere. What am I missing?

Comment: The phrase "*…initial value of this*" infers that you think it will change later. It can't. The value of *this* is set when entering an execution context, it can't be modified later. The question seems to be "*why isn't `this` within a module the global object?*".

Comment: FWIW I found an answer to my question [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396467/a-puzzle-about-this-in-javascript-coffeescript)

Comment: @RobG of course you are right, I have edited the question. (Also I actually didn't really pick up on the fact that running a simple script was indeed a module, though in retrospect I should have, then I could have more easily googled the answer or knew it was `exports` to begin with :) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Node.js, as of now, every file you create is called a module. So, when you run the program in a file, `this` will refer the `module.exports`. You can check that like this

```
console.log(this === module.exports);
// true
```

As a matter of fact, `exports` is just a reference to `module.exports`, so the following will also print `true`

```
console.log(this === exports);
// true
```

Possibly related: [Why 'this' declared in a file and within a function points to different object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894970/1903116)